# Reverse color brewer colors of a ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, colorbrewer

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
x <- LETTERS[1:20]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1, 20))
data <- expand.grid(X = x, Y = y)
data$Z <- runif(400, 0, 5)
```

If I construct the data frame above, and then plot a heat map with the code below I get this and that:

```
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill = Z)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds") +                    # line 3
  # scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", direction = -1) +  # line 4
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I thought running `line #4` in place of `line #3` (above) was supposed to reverse the colors of my legend, according to `?scale_fill_distiller()`:

> `direction` argument: Sets the order of colours in the scale. If 1, the default, colours are as output by RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(). If -1, the order of colours is reversed.

In essence the white areas of the heat map would turn dark red, and the dark red areas of the heat map would turn white. Why isn't this happening? Run `line #3` above, or `line #4` and the output is the same.

[image: heatmap]

Comment: I can't confirm the issue; for me the colours in the heatmap *are* reversed when I do `direction = -1`.

Comment: [Update] Ok, I *can* confirm with your code above. It does work if you explicitly use `direction = 1` and `direction = -1`.

Comment: @Maurits Evers did you comment and uncomment the two lines I have above? I'll troubleshoot on this end. It must be some type of "typo" error by me I imagine. I just commented and uncommented three and four. And I keep getting the same plot. Strange.

Comment: Yeah I just posted an updated comment. If you use `direction = 1` and `direction = -1` it works as expected (see my temp example below). If you omit `direction = 1` it doesn't. Weird.

Comment: @Maurits Evers oah... so the default is `direction = -1` whereas you'd assume (I think) that the default should be `direction = 1`. Is that likely the real issue here?

Comment: Yes, it turns out the default for `direction` in `scale_fill_distiller` is `direction = -1`. You can see that when you type `scale_fill_distiller` plus <Enter> into an R terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to my comment above, let's put both plots side-by-side

```
gg1 <- ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill = Z)) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", direction = +1) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    theme_minimal()

gg2 <- ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill = Z)) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", direction = -1) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    theme_minimal()

library(gridExtra)
g <- grid.arrange(gg1, gg2)
```

[image]

The reason for the behaviour you see above is due to `scale_fill_distiller` assuming `direction = -1` by default:

```
scale_fill_distiller
#function (..., type = "seq", palette = 1, direction = -1, values = NULL,
#    space = "Lab", na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar",
#    aesthetics = "fill")
#{
#    type <- match.arg(type, c("seq", "div", "qual"))
#    if (type == "qual") {
#        warning("Using a discrete colour palette in a continuous scale.\n  Consider using type = \"seq\" or type = \"div\" instead",
#            call. = FALSE)
#    }
#    continuous_scale(aesthetics, "distiller", gradient_n_pal(brewer_pal(type,
#        palette, direction)(7), values, space), na.value = na.value,
#        guide = guide, ...)
#}
#<bytecode: 0x7fed742ed1d8>
#<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```